# Can I use class as a parameter with implemented some method when calling c++ DLL in c# program?

Tags: c#, c++, dll

I know that c# can use callback function when calling c++ DLL paramter

I need to improve callback function so DLL can use one function or function can use depends on parameter number.

But I want to pack some function.

c# source

```
class functionPackager
{
    public void func1();

    public void func2();

    public void func3();
};

class main
{
    ..some operation

    functionPackager cFunc;

    calling c++ dll call (some parameter , cFunc );
}
```

c++/dll

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void call(some parameter , class * func)
{
    some operation..

    //calling c# class method in c++ dll
    func->func1();
    func->func2();
    func->func3();
}
```

Comment: i choose way to passing class as a parameter. first divide member variable and method. variable wrapping with a class, member only class can passing, and sevaral method wrapping with one method, function can deliver function type parameter. function can make different working by function type parameter. i planned to do it. if this is not working. i will comment